# Python: Remove duplicate lists in list of lists

Tags: python

Given list that looks like:

```
list = [["A"], ["B"], ["A","B"], ["B","A"], ["A","B","C"], ["B", "A", "C"]]
```

How do I return

```
final_list = [["A"], ["B"], ["A", "B"], ["A", "B", "C"]]
```

Note that I treat ["A","B"] to be same as  ["B","A"]
and ["A","B","C"] same as ["B", "A", "C"].

Comment: Do you need to maintain order?

Comment: @Boris Nope. order doens't matter

Comment: `final = list(map(list, set(map(frozenset, l))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
list_ = [["A"], ["B"], ["A","B"], ["B","A"], ["A","B","C"], ["B", "A", "C"]]
l = list(map(list, set(map(tuple, map(set, list_)))))
```

**Output** :

```
[['A', 'B'], ['B'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A']]
```

This process goes through like :

1. First convert each sub-list into a set. Thus `['A', 'B']` and `['B', 'A']` both are converted to `{'A', 'B'}`.
2. Now convert each of them to a tuple for removing duplicate items as `set()` operation can not be done with set sub-items in the list.
3. With `set()` operation make a list of unique tuples.
4. Now convert each tuple items in the list into list type.

This is equivalent to :

```
list_ = [['A'], ['B'], ['A', 'B'], ['B', 'A'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'A', 'C']]
l0 = [set(i) for i in list_]
# l0 = [{'A'}, {'B'}, {'A', 'B'}, {'A', 'B'}, {'A', 'B', 'C'}, {'A', 'B', 'C'}]
l1 = [tuple(i) for i in l0]
# l1 = [('A',), ('B',), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'C')]
l2 = set(l1)
# l2 = {('A', 'B'), ('A',), ('B',), ('A', 'B', 'C')}
l = [list(i) for i in l2]
# l = [['A', 'B'], ['A'], ['B'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
```

Comment: you can aso do `l = [list(x) for x in {frozenset(y) for y in my_list}]`

Comment: This answer relies on the fact that `tuple(set([ ... something ... ]))` always returns the elements in the same order. While that might actually be the case for some Python implementations, the language does not guarantee it in any way. I just found an example where that assumption is broken: `tuple(set([27,28,29,30,31,32,0]))` -> `(32, 0, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31)`, whereas `tuple(set([0,27,28,29,30,31,32]))` -> `(0, 32, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31)`.

Comment: So, the answers here that are always going to work are those based on sorting element lists, or using `frozenset`, but not the `tuple(set(...))` mapping.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

```
lst = [["A"], ["B"], ["A","B"], ["B","A"], ["A","B","C"], ["B", "A", "C"]]

print([
    list(i) 
    for i in sorted(
        set(
            tuple(sorted(i)) 
            for i in lst
        ), 
        key=lambda k: (len(k), k)
    )
])
```

Prints:

```
[['A'], ['B'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
```

Answer (score 1):

When the data you want to handle has to be both unique and unordered, a better choice of data structure are `set` and `frozenset`.

A [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) is an unordered container of unique values.

A [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) is a `set` which cannot be mutated, it is thus hashable which allows it to be contained into another `set`.

### Example

```
lst = [["A"], ["B"], ["A","B"], ["B","A"], ["A","B","C"], ["B", "A", "C"]]    

data = {frozenset(el) for el in lst}

print(data)
```

### Output

```
{frozenset({'B'}), frozenset({'A', 'B'}), frozenset({'A', 'C', 'B'}), frozenset({'A'})}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [["A"], ["B"], ["A","B"], ["B","A"], ["A","B","C"], ["B", "A", "C"]]
[list(i) for i in {tuple(sorted(i)) for i in l}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a equality partition. It works on any list of any type that has equality defined for it. This is worse than a hash partition as it is quadratic time.

```
def partition(L, key=None):

    if key is None:
        key = lambda x: x

    parts = []
    for item in L:
        for part in parts:
            if key(item) == key(part[0]):
               part.append(item)
               break
        else:
            parts.append([item])
    return parts

def unique(L, key=None):
    return [p[0] for p in partition(L, key=key)]

alist = [["A"], ["B"], ["A","B"], ["B","A"], ["A","B","C"], ["B", "A", "C"]]

unique(alist)
# results in [['A'], ['B'], ['A', 'B'], ['B', 'A'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'A', 'C']]

unique(alist, key=lambda v: tuple(sorted(v)))
# results in [['A'], ['B'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
```